# npmrc multiple registries for the same scope

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-registry

Is it possible to contain multiple registries for the same scope? In my company, we use `@mycompany` scope for both public NPM registry as well as internal registries.

I tried to do

```
@mycompany:registry=https://company.registry.com
@mycompany:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
```

but this did not work.

Comment: A RFC has been opened about this : https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/211

Comment: I have the same problem in Github packages. Azure Devops does have upstream registries to solve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot. Unfortunately `npm` can handle only one scope peer registry. But you might use a proxy as [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/) for that that handle the distribution for you.
https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/uplinks

I will mock an example of configuration using **Verdaccio**:

I mocked a "company registry" with no external access (http://localhost:5000/).

```
storage: /Users/test/.local/share/verdaccio/storage_company_registry

auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd   
packages:
  '@*/*':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated

  '**':
    access: $all
    publish: $all
middlewares:
  audit:
    enabled: true
logs:
  - {type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http}
```

As you can see, no remotes (uplink) configured, it's completely offline.

Then I'll run my proposal, [Verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio) (http://localhost:4873/) that ask first to the company registry and if the package is not found there, it will fetch from the public registry (npmjs).

```
storage: /Users/test/.local/share/verdaccio/storage_proxy

auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
  company:
    url: https://company.registry.com

packages:
  '@company/*':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    proxy: company npmjs  
  '**':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    proxy: npmjs
middlewares:
  audit:
    enabled: true
logs:
  - {type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http}
```

As a PoC (I am switching @company by @babel) I run `npm install @babel/types --registry http://localhost:4873/`. The result is the following

```
 warn --- config file  - /Users/test/.config/verdaccio/config.yaml
 warn --- Plugin successfully loaded: htpasswd
 warn --- Plugin successfully loaded: audit
 warn --- http address - http://localhost:4873/ - verdaccio/4.0.0-alpha.4
 http --> 404, req: 'GET http://localhost:5000/@babel%2Ftypes' (streaming)
 http --> 404, req: 'GET http://localhost:5000/@babel%2Ftypes', bytes: 0/43
 http --> 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2Ftypes' (streaming)
 http --> 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2Ftypes', bytes: 0/93375
 http <-- 200, user: null(127.0.0.1), req: 'GET /@babel%2ftypes', bytes: 0/22072
 http --> 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esutils' (streaming)
 http --> 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esutils', bytes: 0/23169
 http <-- 200, user: null(127.0.0.1), req: 'GET /esutils', bytes: 0/3854
 http --> 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/to-fast-properties' (streaming)
 http --> 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/to-fast-properties', bytes: 0/8239
 http <-- 200, user: null(127.0.0.1), req: 'GET /to-fast-properties', bytes: 0/1725
 http --> 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash' (streaming)
 http --> 200, req: 'GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash', bytes: 0/185410
 http <-- 200, user: null(127.0.0.1), req: 'GET /lodash', bytes: 0/14307
 http <-- 200, user: null(127.0.0.1), req: 'POST /-/npm/v1/security/audits/quick', bytes: 474/146
```

Your node package manager will speak with (http://localhost:4873/) and Verdaccio will try fo fetch package from the internal registry, the result is 404, in the second iteration will fetch the package from npmjs, resulting in a 200.

Having a proxy registry makes the process more transparent for your team, all is centralized and more efficient, ihmo.

I hope that helps.